# What is the difference between pressing Alt+Tab and Ctrl+Alt+Tab?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, window

When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, then I get a window to switch between windows. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, I get the same result. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12445/windows-keyboard-shortcuts)

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Switch between open apps.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Use the arrow keys to switch between all open apps.

In other words:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> Switches between open apps ***immediately*** after releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> *key*.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> *Opens a quasi-dialogue window*  where you use the arrow keys to walk over all open apps *and you need to **press*** <kbd>Enter</kbd> *(or click a mouse button) to confirm your choice*.

Comment: There's also shift+alt+tab which does the same thing as alt+tab but traverses the list in reverse

Comment: There's also CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+TAB which does what you'd expect!

Comment: There's also Win + Tab which does a similar thing to CTRL + ALT + TAB, but on multiple monitors and lets you create virtual desktops and switch between them

Comment: Shift generally reverses navigation shortcuts. For example Ctrl+Tab switches to the next tab in a browser, Ctrl+Shift+Tab goes backwards. Tab moves to the next input, Shift+Tab to previous one etc. Some programs even use Ctrl+Shift+Z to redo (reverse undo which is Ctrl+Z).

Comment: There's also Alt+Escape which sends the current window to the back of the Z order, and Alt+Shift+Escape which brings the window at the back of the Z order to the front - which also avoids restoring all your minimised windows.

Comment: You can still use the arrows in the ALT+TAB dialog, too. Just leave ALT pressed.

Comment: Don't forget Ctrl+Win+Alt+Tab, which cycles through the icons only.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You can't use arrows in the `Ctrl+Win+Alt+Tab` window but you can do `Ctrl+Win+Alt+Tab` to cycle forwards and `Ctrl+Shift+Win+Alt+Tab` to cycle backwards and I think that's a beautiful combination of keys to be able to press. Also, just tested, `Alt-Gr+Win+Tab` works too but that's no fun (If you don't have `Alt-Gr` key you might have some luck with the `Right-Alt` key.

Comment: I can't say I've ever used the `Ctrl` variation, I've always just left `Alt` pressed like @ForNeVeR says. It ends up being quicker than having to hit `Enter` at the end.

Comment: This is wrong—the arrow keys are not the difference. Both modes do that. The difference is that the picker stays open after you release the keys if you used Ctrl—with just Alt+Tab, releasing the keys selects the one you chose. With Ctrl+Alt+Tab, releasing the keys does nothing, so you can still select from the options presented (by arrows, by mouse, by Tab or Shift+Tab, perhaps others).

Comment: @JohnHamilton You can also do `Win + Alt + Ctrl + Shift + Caps Lock + Tab`, which does exactly what you’d expect (i.e., cycles backwards through icons while also toggling caps lock).

Comment: @KRyan Not exactly wrong, but just has missing info. You could just suggest an edit though ;)

Comment: Yes, but what good is the choice of modes? `Ctrl` works only before you press `Tab`, but the info you need to choose mode (the picker window) appears only after you press `Tab`.

Answer (score 40):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will let you select the application, and when you release the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, you will be switched to the window you selected. With <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, the selection screen will remain displayed, and you will have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to actually change the focus.

Answer (score 8):

> 1. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>   Switches to the next open window
> 2. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>    Switches to the previous open window
> 3. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>   Cycles through open windows, and switches to the window 
>      when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is released. This is known as Coolswitch. Pressing 
>      <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels switching windows.
> 4. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>    Cycles backwards through open windows, and
>          switches to the window when the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is released. This is known
>          as    Coolswitch. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels switching windows.
> 5. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> Vista: Starts Windows Coolswitch. Use Arrow keys,
>      <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate.
>      Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels switching windows.
> 6. <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>  Toggle speech dictation mode.  Vista: Cycles through
>      Taskbar buttons, Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate a window. This is 
>      same as <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in older versions.
> 7. <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>    Cycles through Taskbar buttons, Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> 
>      to activate a window.  Vista: Cycles through open windows using
>      Windows Flip3D. Release keys to activate window. Pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>
>      cancels switching windows.
> 8. <kbd>Winkey</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>  Cycles through parts of the desktop and
>      taskbar.  Vista: Starts Windows Flip3D. Use Arrow keys, <kbd>Tab</kbd>, or
>      <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to navigate and <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate. Pressing
>      <kbd>Esc</kbd> cancels switching windows.

From *Shortcut Keys and Key Modifiers* at https://onedrive.live.com/?id=E2F0CE17A268A4FA%21121&cid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA

Answer (score 0):

There is just difference that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> leaves your window selection on screen when you release the keys.

By the way, you can hover over the window with your mouse and click to select the chosen one.